# Remove “Quit” from Mac OS X app’s dock-menu

Tags: macos, qt, quit

I am building a Qt application on Mac OS X using Qt-4.7.
In my application there is a Dock Menu, I want to remove the “Quit” option from it.
How can I achieve this?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as with the items "Show all windows" and "Hide", there is no way to remove these.

Similar to
[Cocoa : Hide items in dock menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644964/cocoa-hide-items-in-dock-menu?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very difficult operation, this is beyond my knowledge but i believe this is possible. I do know an alternitive solution you can use:
Make the app invisible which does not show in dock or in the apple menu:
Add This to your apps Info.plist File:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```