# Cocoa : Hide items in dock menu

Tags: cocoa, dock, nsmenu

Is there a way to hide the "Show all windows" & "Hide" items of the app's dock contextual menu ?

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not. Those menu items are internal to the Dock; the application has no control over them.